# Getting the oldest datas from a table that are older than a 100 days

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I've been struggling with the following problem:

**EXPLAINING**

I have a table called `part_subhourly_data` that holds production data for a part (For the purpose of the problem, no need to know what a part is).

I need to archive the any data older than a 100 days. But since there's a lot of data (they arrive each 5 or 10 minutes) and we have more than 1000 parts, I need to do it the 5 oldest days each time.

This is the schema of my table:

```
part_subhourly_data
  id INTERGER, 
  part_id INTEGER, 
  produced_at TIMESTAMP
  data HSTORE
```

So basically I need to get all data that is in this table, where produced_at is prior to 100 days ago and limit that to the first 5 days, per part.

Example:

`Part 1` has data from 15 Aug 2016 until 12 Dec 2016
`Part 2` has data from 1st Sep 2016 until 12 Dec 2016

100 days ago would be 3 Sep 2016.

For `Part 1` I would take data from 15 Aug 2016 until 19 Aug 2016 (5 days). 
For `Part 2` I would take data from 1st Sep 2016 until 3 Sep 2016 (3 days because of the 100 days old condition).

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED**

Well, I'm using rails on this, but a SQL solution is welcome as well. For now, What I'm doing is to grab the oldest data with:

```
SELECT "part_subhourly_data"."part_id", MIN(produced_at) produced_at
  FROM "part_subhourly_data"
  WHERE (produced_at < (NOW() - INTERVAL '100 days'))
  GROUP BY "part_subhourly_data"."part_id"
```

And then I loop Over each part_id and grab the data based on the `MIN(produced_at)`. It works, but it doesn't seems ideal. I'm sure that there is some SQL magic to make it simpler, and quicker, without having to loop over each part.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take all records where **produced_at** is prior to 100 days ago.
dense rank the records per **part_id** ordered by **produced_at::date** in ascending order.
The records with the oldest date will get **1**, the records with the next oldest date will get **2** etc.

```
select  part_id,produced_at

from   (select  part_id,produced_at
               ,dense_rank () over (partition by part_id order by produced_at::date)  as dr      

        from    part_subhourly_data

        where   produced_at < now() - interval '100 days'
        ) p

where   dr <= 5     
;
```

Comment: Wouldn't this limit to the first 5 datas instead of the datas included in the first 5 days?

Comment: No, we're using dense_rank and not row_number. All rows with the same part_id and produced_at will get the same number. P.s. I suggest next time to put a data sample in your post.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. It takes the first 5 datas. Remember that produced_at is a TIMESTAMP and We have data every 5, 10, 15 minutes (and other intervals too).

Comment: P.s. we're taking the last 5 days **that contain data**. Is that O.k. with you?

Comment: That's what I want. If no data, no need to grab it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130400/discussion-between-dudu-markovitz-and-lcguida).